# relax exception catch necessity

Tags: java, checked-exceptions

Is there a possibility in Java to get rid of the necessity to catch non-`RuntimeException` exceptions? Maybe compiler flags?

I know the reason why the catching is promoted, but want to do simple and straight tools that enforce their requirements. So if something can went wrong I don't like to catch up but exit the application, crashing with a meaningful exception. Usually this ends up like:

```
try {
     connection.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

which introduces 4 lines of code mess, and introduces the wrapping `RuntimeException` mess on error output. Sometimes it even motivate people to wrap large `try ... catch (Throwable ..)` blocks around anything, which is the likely cause for our beloved 'Unknown error occured' alert boxes...

Comment: Maybe throw a more meaningful unchecked exception? It's not that bad if you can encapsulate those four lines into a single class or static method.

Comment: it sounds like you might want to establish a convention for handling exceptions in your application. The more times I read this question, it appears that there are places where exceptions need to be truly handled, and other places where the application must terminate.

Comment: for exceptions on close where it is unlikely that you are going to do anything on exception, People tend to write a `closeQuietly` method similar to `IOUtils.closeQuietly` but for connections.

Comment: I like the meaningfulness of Java's exception, so I see no need for me to add anything. Every custom exception would obfuscate or in mild form complicate the true origin of application failure in debug output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility in Java to get rid of the necessity to catch non-RuntimeException exceptions?

For a checked exception, you can chose between catching the exception and declaring it in the method header as thrown.

> Maybe compiler flags?

No.  There are no compiler flags to relax this.  It is a fundamental part of the language design.  Relaxing the checked exception rules via a compiler switch would cause serious library interoperability problems.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `throws` keyword with method prototype to avoid `try-catch` block. which eventually throws the exception to JVM's Default Exception handler which halts the application if no catch block's are specified in your code to handle the exception raised.

Comment: Won't work if method is overriding a non-`throws` method, like `Thread.run()`

Answer (score 3):

Crashing the application at the first sight of an exception is **very** bad practice. Especially when some work is unsaved and the application is using some resources that *needs* to be freed and cleaned before the application terminates execution. Some very popular software used to do that... and instead of "fixing" the issue, they introduced a data recoverability features on application restart. However the trick, this is not good software engineering.

At the very least, your application should not crash on the first exception/error encountered, but recover with a meaningful message. It is being lazy to just wrap everything in a `RuntimeException` (or even `Throwable`) and, especially, not do anything with it.

Java does not support flags of any kind because there are 1) a workaround, and 2) better ways to handle this situation. For example :

**1. Handle the exception in the calling method**

You can add the `throws` keyword in your method declaration, up to your `static public void main` method, which, if not handling the exception, will eventually crash the application with a stacktrace.

```
class Foo {
   public void someMethod(....) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
      ...
   }

   static public void main(String...args) throws Throwable {
      new Foo().someMethod();
   } 
}
```

This method does not offer any means of recoverability and will probably make your user unhappy (with a big meaningless stachtrace if they ran the application from a console, or just nothing at all if they launched it from a shortcut or GUI). Also, if you have some acquired resources, you will not be able to clean them when an exception occurs. At the very least, your `main` should `catch (Throwable e)` and output something before throwing the exception above. Something like :

```
class Foo {
   public void someMethod(....) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
      ...
   }

   static public void main(String...args) {
      try {
         new Foo().someMethod();
      } catch (...) {
         // output or log exception here and, optionally, cleanup and exit
      }
   } 
}
```

** **EDIT** **

Consider this scenario : a program is initializing some resource for processing some data, then some runtime exception (or error) occurs during processing, the application crash, but the resources are not released or freed. In Java, however, one could do this

```
public E doSomething() throws RuntimeException {
   // declare a bunch of resources

   try {
      // process resources with unchecked exceptions
   } finally {
      // free resources
   }

   // return some result
}
```

and cleanly exit the method on error or on success, perhaps even logging the runtime error for "posterity".

**2. Log the error and return some meaningful value**

Logging is a very good practice. You can show your user some message telling them that the operation could not be executed without crashing the whole thing, and giving you some traces of what and where the user were doing. A simplistic logging system could be :

```
class Foo {
   static private final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName());

   public boolean doSomethingImpl(...) {
      boolean result = true;
      try {
        ...
      } catch (SomeException e) {
         LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "meaningful message why method could not do something!", e);
         result = false;
      }
      return result;
   }

   public void doSomething() {
      if (!doSomethingImpl(...)) {
          // handle failure here
      }
   }
}
```

By default, the `Logger` will output everything to the `err` output stream, but you can add your own handlers :

```
// loggers are singletons, so you can retrieve any logger at anytime from
// anywhere, as long as you know the logger's name
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName());

logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);  // disable output to err
logger.addHandler(new MyHandler());  // MyHandler extends java.util.logging.Handler
```

Java already ships with some default logging handlers, one of which [writes to file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/JavalogFileHandlerDemo.htm).

etc.

Comment: "Crashing the application at the first sight of an exception is very bad practice. Especially when some work is unsave." ok. But when writing small cmd line applications or plugin-like executables, there is no work to loose and every unneccessery line of code or borked debug output is bad pratice for me. The java exception error output with it's code position is fine for me. Some other reliable tools work like this, for example `rsync`, that logs the code file and line number on failiure.

Comment: I understand for small tools/plugins/etc., perhaps. However I still think that good habits should be applied even if not really necessary. There is no program so small for bad code. IMO anyway.

Comment: Well I came upon this question on the way for good code... I have a preference for minimalistic, small code and thus I dislike Java's predefined checking enforcement on some `Exception`s.

Comment: @dronus, then I believe that you don't fully understand the point of having exceptions; Java has exceptions for good reasons. Among one of them `An exception is an event, which occurs during the execution of a program, that disrupts the normal flow of the program's instructions.` Exceptions make it possible to branch on different, possible events; unlike simply returning null (or 0) or relying on calling another method to find out the what/why/where. I suggest you read the whole section, more specifically http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: Well exactly that is what I want. On the occurence of some problem, the normal flow of the programs instructions should be disrupted, and in my case, the program should terminate instantly, describing the problem to `stderr`. But Java enforces me to catch SOME exceptions and do a special handling on my own. So if I decide to exit the program on these ones either, I have to write extra rethrow code and the resulting `stderr` output is usually different from that of an uncatched `RuntimeException`. Thats the whole fact I dislike and wanted to get rid of, which as it seems is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's any way around this for the JVM.  Your best bet is to have your methods re-throw the exception, which gets rid of the "mess" in your code, and then have your main program throw Exception.  This should propagate the error up to the top of your program.

Keep in mind, however, that the place where the exception actually happens is a much better place to let the user know what happened (i.e., exactly what it was doing when this particular IOException happened).  You'll lose this resolution if all errors are simply propagated up to the top level.

Comment: 'Your best bet is to have your methods re-throw the exception' is often not possible if overriding framework method. For example the `Thread.run()` method does not allow to throw exceptions away.

Answer (score 1):

You do have the ability to throw your exceptions up a level. Here's an example

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        super();
    }
    public void disconnect(connection) throws IOException {
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible if overriding framework methods like `Thread.run()`

Comment: Ah thanks, I was unaware of that. Haven't really run into thread management in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Throws" to avoid the error..but it will not be good programimg practice